# How to generate JWT in Power BI using OAuth 2 for REST API's

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

Here is the query that I am using to generate JWT tokens with OAuth2 but it is not working well maybe I am missing something

```
    GetJson = Web.Contents("https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx-xxx-xxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
        [
            Headers = [#"Accept" = "application/json",
                #"Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
            ],
            Content = Text.ToBinary(
                Uri.BuildQueryString(
                    [
                        client_id = "xxx-xxx-xxxxx", 
                        client_secret = "xxx-xxx-xxxxx", 
                        resource = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx-xxx-xxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token",
                        scope = "xxx-xxx-xxxxx",
                        grant_type = "authorization_code"
                    ]
                )
            )
        ]
    ),
    access_token =GetJson
in
    access_token
```

Getting this error in table [image: The request body must contain the following parameter:'client_id']